# c# is there a way to simplify a nested function

Tags: c#, dictionary

I got a helper class for dictionary to update value. Here is what the code looks like:

```
public static void UpdateWithAggregate(
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, 
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<string, double>>> data,
    string key1,
    string key2,
    string key3,
    double value)
{
    if (!data.ContainsKey(key1))
    {
        data[key1] = 
            new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<string, double>>();
    }
    UpdateWithAggregate(data[key1], key2, key3, value);
}

public static void UpdateWithAggregate(
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<string, double>> data,
    string key1,
    string key2,
    double value)
{
    if (!data.ContainsKey(key1))
    {
        data[key1] = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, double>();
    }
    UpdateWithAggregate(data[key1], key2, value);
}

public static void UpdateWithAggregate(
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, double> data,
    string key1,
    double value)
{
    if (!data.ContainsKey(key1))
    {
        data[key1] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        data[key1] += value;
    }
}
```

I wonder if There is a way that I could use a single function and take arbitrary nested dictionary and their keys and do the add.

Comment: You could switch to using a tuple for the key instead `ConcurrentDictionary<(string,string,string), double>` and then just write a generic version of `UpdateWithAggregate`.

Comment: Just a note, it's safer to use the the TryGetValue/TryAdd than using the Item[TKey] property. The Item[TKey] property does the same things as a GetOrAdd which is not atomic. So two threads can race to set a key, in which case you may end up with an unexpected value. See the remarks at the bottom of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_GetOrAdd__0__1_